# Uncaught ReferenceError: Activetab is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
(function Activetab () {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            removeActive();
            e.target.classList.add('active');
         })
    }
})();

function removeActive() {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
}
window.onload = Activetab();
window.onload = removeActive();
```

For some reason when  I try to use `window.onload = Activetab();` 
return

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Activetab is not defined

What is wrong? Why window.onload funcion can't listen Activetab function

Comment: simply remove the ()() which wraps the function Activatetab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're immediately invoking the function `Activetab`, you need to read more about **[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).**

I don't know why do you want to execute that function immediately, but this is probably the approach you're looking for:

```
function Activetab () {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            removeActive();
            e.target.classList.add('active');
         })
    }
};

function removeActive() {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
    for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
}
window.onload = Activetab; // Just assign the function
window.onload = removeActive; // Just assign the function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, dont make it an IIFE

```
function Activetab () {
        var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                removeActive();
                e.target.classList.add('active');
            })
        }
    }
```

or keep it as an IIFE and remove `window.onload = Activetab();`
IIFE's are immediately invoked so no need to call it

IIFE's can also be anonymous.